# how to replace this part of string - Ã¢Â€Â¢

Tags: jquery, json, string, api

I'm pulling in a string from an API, which has the characters: Ã¢Â€Â¢, which should instead be a bullet point, or at least a '-'.

I cant figure out how to replace this in my code using .replace()?

```
.replace('Ã¢Â€Â¢', '-');
```

the above code does not work.

I've also noticed that in the raw string given from the API I'm pulling this from, the characters are capitalised, whereas when I display them through my code, they are lower case?

perhaps this may be part of the issue

Comment: You have some sort of encoding problem - so see that you solve _that_, instead of trying to replace stuff.

Answer (score 1):

[`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) does not work like that. If you pass in a string as the first parameter, it replaces *instances of the string as a whole*. Obviously this will do nothing unless all those characters appear one after another in the exact same order in your input.

The correct syntax to replace all instances of certain characters is using a regular expression:

```
str.replace(/[Ã¢Â€Â¢]/g, '-');
```